# Z3 using parseSMTLIB2String in Java API delivers false UNSAT once it devilverd one UNSAT

Tags: z3, smt

My implementation of the Z3 SMT solver is rough, but I found the Java API to be very inaccessible.
I use parseSMTLIB2String and it does the job well, until a SAT-check returns one UNSATISFIABLE. It then continues to return UNSATISFIABLE even with previous values that returned SATISFIABLE. Am I using the solver wrong?

```
public static Boolean checkSat(int checkMakespan, Flowshop fs) {
    String smtString = FlowShopSmtGen.generateSMTFromFlowshop(fs, checkMakespan);
    HashMap<String, String> cfg = new HashMap<>();
    Context ctx = new Context(cfg);
    BoolExpr fsresult = ctx.parseSMTLIB2String(smtString, null, null, null, null);

    Solver solver = ctx.mkSolver();
    solver.add(fsresult);
    Status s = solver.check();
    System.out.println(s);

    if (s == Status.SATISFIABLE) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: adding     ctx.close();
        solver.reset(); did NOT do the trick

Comment: This looks OK, but the behavior depends on what you pass in smtString. If you think it's a bug please open an issue on our issue tracker, including all strings and version numbers for all the tools involved. The issue tracker is here: https://github.com/z3prover/z3/issues

Answer (score 0):

If you add assertions to an already unsatisfiable set of assertions, it is expected that you keep obtaining unsatisfiable as an answer.

But if you have popped some assertions in-between, then there might be something suspect.